# Google Earth Engine - Extracting Sentinel 1

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to extract values of Sentinel 1 and Sentinel 2 images at polygon locations. For Sentinel 2 it works perfectly, for Sentinel 1 I only get empty feature collections back (see code below).

Does anybody know why both Image(Collections) behave differently and what I can do about it?

```
var aoi = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[9.019937831719055, 51.48145834488721],
          [9.019937831719055, 51.45675655955112],
          [9.104566890556946, 51.45675655955112],
          [9.104566890556946, 51.48145834488721]]], null, false);



var gedi = ee.FeatureCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_B_002/GEDI02_B_2021003022816_O11669_02_T07098_02_003_01_V002');


gedi = gedi.filterBounds(aoi).randomColumn();
var gedi_sample = gedi.filter(ee.Filter.lt("random", 0.1));


gedi_sample = gedi_sample.map(function(f){return f.buffer(15)})
print(gedi_sample, "gedi_sample")


var sen1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD")
  .filterBounds(gedi_sample)
  .filterDate('2020-12-29' , '2021-01-08')
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', "VV"))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', "VH"))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
  .filterMetadata('resolution_meters', 'equals' , 10)
  .select("VV", "VH")
  .toBands();


var sen2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterBounds(gedi_sample)
  .filterDate('2020-12-29' , '2021-01-08')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 80))
  .select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'SCL')
  .toBands();



Map.addLayer(sen1, {}, "Sen1")
Map.addLayer(sen2, {}, "Sen2")
Map.addLayer(gedi_sample, {color: "red"}, "gedi_sample")

print(sen1, "Sen1")
print(sen2, "Sen2")

var sample_sen1 = sen1
  .sampleRegions({collection: gedi_sample,
                  properties: ["pai"],
                  scale:10,
                  geometries: true
  })



var sample_sen2 = sen2
  .sampleRegions({collection: gedi_sample,
                  properties: ["pai"],
                  scale:10,
                  geometries: true
  })

print(sample_sen1, "Samples Sen1")
print(sample_sen2, "Samples Sen2")
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4c71c1ca1bb0b10b400f5a8ef2f153a4

Answer (score 1):

If you just inspect your inputs, you can see that not every image covers the area you're working in equally.  Some points are masked, and `sampleRegions` drops any points that contain masked pixels.

[image]

If you really want to go this route (you probably don't, since it's hard to work with features that have an unequal number of properties), you can use `reduceRegions` with a `first` reducer instead of `sampleRegions`.

```
var sample_sen1 = sen1.reduceRegions({
  collection: gedi_sample,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  scale:10,                  
})
```

Another option is `unmasking` the inputs with some nodata value, but that has similar issues (ie: you still can't pass that to a classifier as training data).